# How can a single Curve Interpolation Mode set to Constant?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

In order to animate a character so that it grabs an object an throws it, I added a *Child-Of constrained* and keyframed its influence. In the *F-curve Editor* I can't set the curve which controls the influence to interpolation-mode *Constant* without changing the other curves (Which should be linear or bezier).

How can the interpolation mode of a curve changed independently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select **left-click-select every single Key** in the Graph editor and press <kbd>T</kbd> to change the interpolation. This will always only affect the interpolation **up to the next key** of that one curve.

Further controls for this:

- <kbd>A</kbd> deselects all keys, just like in edit-mode.
- <kbd>L</kbd> selects all keys of the curve of which one key is currently selected.
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> locks the selected curve to prevent it from being edited.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the interpolation type can be done per keyframe on a curve, the interpolation between the selected keyframe and the next defines the final curve shape. Selecting one keyframe and pressing <kbd>L</kbd> will select all keyframes on the curve.

If you are having trouble finding or selecting a single curve in the graph editor you may want to lock all curves and then unlock the one you want to change. <kbd>Tab</kbd> will lock/unlock all curves. You can also click the group lock (see green LocRotScale line below) to toggle all curves in that group, then unlock the one curve you wish to alter. With all other curves locked you can use <kbd>A</kbd> to select all the keyframes on the one unlocked curve.

The cursor button [image]on the header of the graph editor can also help by only showing the curves for objects selected in the 3DView.

<kbd>T</kbd> will show the menu to choose what interpolation to use on the selected keyframes.

[image]

Also the Dopesheet and graph editor work similarly, you may find the dopesheet an easier way to select the keyframes you want. The same <kbd>T</kbd> shortcut will let you change interpolations in the dopesheet.

[image]